# How to check for anything in object chain and rescue on undefined to return false?

Tags: javascript

If you have a javascript chain like the following:

```
user.status.lastOnline ## cannot read property 'status' of undefined
```

Then this simply errors out and you can't do something like

```
user.status.lastOnline ? 'today' : 'never'
```

Is there a graceful way to chain objects that return false at any point in the chain? Any convenience method for this?

I.e would do:

```
attempt(user.status.lastOnline) ? 'today' : 'never'
```

and if status was undefined it'd evaluate to false.

Comment: You'd have to make your own method - not really a graceful way to check.

Comment: Any idea how to go about that? @tymeJV

Comment: What about try ... catch ...?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a built-in function to do that, but you could write your own or use a library.

In this example you pass the path elements as an array, rather than a dotted string, because it's easier to deal with object keys that contain dots.

```
function get(rootObject, path) {
  var result = rootObject;

  // use .every instead of .forEach to control when the loop stops
  path.every(function(nextName) {
    var next = result[nextName];
    if(next !== "undefined") {
        result = next;
    }

    return next;
  });

  // return false on incomplete path, as per question
  return result || false;
}

var obj = var obj = { a: 1, b: { c: 2}, d: { "e.f": "g" }, h: [ { first: true }] } 
get(obj, ["a", "x"]); // false
get(obj, ["b", "c"]); // 2
get(obj, ["d", "e.f]) // "g"
get(obj, ["h", 0, "first"]) // true
```

If you are willing to use a library, [`_.get`](http://devdocs.io/lodash/index#get) from [lodash](https://lodash.com/) works well:

`_.get(user, "status.lastOnline")`.

`_.get` is available from npm as a standalone package, [lodash.get](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.get), so you don't need to depend on the whole of lodash to use it.

It is well tested, efficient and deals with edge cases like dotted keys. It is, however, significantly larger than the above function. Filesize is around 12kb, or 4kb minified and gzipped.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var attempt = function( object, path ) {
    var last = object,
        is_exists = true;

    path.split( '.' ).forEach( function( key ) {
        if ( is_exists && last[ key ] !== undefined ) {
            last = last[ key ];
        } else {
            is_exists = false;
        }
    } );

    return is_exists ? last : false;
};

var obj = {
    a: {
        b: {
            c: 1
        }
    }
};

attempt( obj, 'a.b.c' );// returns 1
attempt( obj, 'a.b' );// returns {c: 1}
attempt( obj, 'a.z' );// returns false
```

Answer (score 1):

Premise: I think it's more convenient to normalize your data and ensuring that all expected properties are set (with null maybe, but set).

If it's not possible, I think that the only possibility to do what you want, as said in other answers, is to pass by a string representation of the object. There is no other way. But I could agree that's a little bit annoying due lack of autocomplete and syntax highlighting in our IDE.

So, a possible middle way, is to make a function that auto builds your nested object if the full path is not set. At start of your block (but after the declaration) you call this function, then do your stuff without other checks:

```
var user = {
    say : {
        hello: {
            world : 1
        }
    }
};

ensure("user.status", window);
ensure("user.say.hello", window); //useless here but must not break

console.log(user.status.lastOnline? 1 : 0); // 0
console.log(user.say.hello.world? "yes" : "no"); // yes
console.log(user.say.hello.baby? "yes" : "no"); // no

// closure with a trick
(function() {
    var user = {say:{hello:{world:1}}};

    user = ensure("user.status", {user:user} );

    console.log(user.status.lastOnline? "yes" : "no");
    console.log(user.say.hello.world? "yes" : "no");

})();
```

`ensure` is defined in this way:

```
function ensure(obj, root) {
    var parts = obj.split("."), k;
    k = parts.shift();
    if(typeof root[k] === "undefined") {
        root[k] = {};
    }
    if(parts.length > 0) {
        ensure(parts.join("."), root[k]);
    }
    // for closure
    return root[k];
}
```

Another solution is to create a static object `user` with ALL property set, and after use a function like `jQuery.extend` (handmade is not so complex to do) in order to override the properties.